# Method checking and proof of differentiability for the given function

Tags: calculus, functions

> Let $f :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$  be a continuous function such that $f (x^2) =
>  f (x^3)$ for all $x$ ∈ $\mathbb{R}$ . Consider the following
> statements.
>
> (I) f is an odd function
>
> (II) f is an even function
>
> (III) f is differentiable everywhere.
>
> Which of them are true ?

My method was as f is continuous for all $R$ putting $x = -t$ in the equation we get $f (t^2) =f (-t^3) = f (t^3)$ from this taking the last two I can say $f (-x) = f (x)$, for differentiability I would need to check limit $\frac{f (x)-f (a)}{x-a}$, but here how do we check to conclude differentiability too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question III.

Let $y>0$.  Then $y=x^3$ for some $x>0$ and $x^2 = y^{3/2}$.  So
we have $f(y) = f(y^{3/2})$.

Let $y \in (0,1)$.  Now let $y_n = y^{(3/2)^n}$.  Then $y_n \to 0$ and $f(y_n) = f(y)$ for all $n$.
Since $f$ is continuous and $y_n \to 0$, we have $f(0)=f(y)$.  So $f$ is constant on $[0,1)$.  As we know $f$ is even, we have $f$ is constant on $(-1,1)$.

Similarly, let $y > 0$.  Taking $y_n = y^{(2/3)^n}$ we have $y_n \to 1$, so $f(y) = f(1)$.  And again, $f$ is even so now we know $f$ is constant on $\mathbb R$.

Not only is $f$ differentiable, but $f'(x) = 0$ for all $x$.